# Massive Parent-Child and delegate pattern

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, composite, delegation

I'm facing with a complex design problem. Due to a hard designed graphic I can't use Apple navigation pattern as `UINavigationController` or other ones.
This is the app diagram
[image: App diagram]

**Black arrow:** protocols direction
**Blue arrow:** parent-child pattern direction

I created this flow because I want to maintain the code inside the single `ViewController` clear and isolated: I thought about them as **modules** that they can be used somewhere in other apps.
The `RootViewController` is the `MainVCs` position manager. It decides which is the current view-controller that it must be showed and it configures it based on its status (modified by delegate methods).
The single `MainVC` doesn't know that `RootVC` exists and it call Root using protocols. The single `ChildViewController` doesn't know that its `MainVC` exists and it call the Main using protocols and so on.

Code is clear and much easy to understand, my purpose, but when I have to apply a modify to the skeleton (`RootVC`) from the `ChildViewControllerN`, child of the umpteenth `ChildViewController`, child of the umpteenth `MainViewController`, I have to propagate the protocol until the `RootViewController`.

**My first question is**: is this pattern correct? What do you think about it?

**My second question is**: is there a *limit point* where I haven't to use delegate pattern but something like `KVO`?

**ADDING**
I read a university lecture about the `composite pattern` that it says:

> **A composite object knows its contained components, that is, its children. Should components maintain a reference to their parent component?**
>   Depends on application, but having these references supports the Chain of Responsibility pattern

So, according to the Chain, I can maintain a reference of the parent but I have to declare a custom interface for this kind of reference. However, doing this I will decrease the number of protocols, but the **second question still be unanswered**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opinion:

When I go beyond a single level of parent/child relationships, I tend to stop using delegates and move to `NSNotification`.  Frequently, I go **directly** to `NSNotification` to reduce dependencies.  I prefer that to KVO because it is explicit, whereas KVO is harder to debug as the project progresses.

(Example: what looks like a simple variable assignment on a background thread results in a hard-to-diagnose crash if a listener is deallocated on the main thread between the moment of assignment and the KVO delivery.)

Comment: `NSNotification` is a choice, but I don't like it because the observer can remove itself as observer for the keyPath. I won't it, I think that the `possible` receiver always has to receive the message. I think also that, maybe, the parent won't always propagate the child message to its *super*parent.

Comment: No matter what method you use, a receiver can always find a way to ignore the message if it tries.  There's no need for propagation among individual objects; each observer registers independently.